A.s. Convergence implies subsequential Complete convergence?
The question tries to understand how much stronger is complete convergence as opposed to almost sure convergence. If results that highlight this relationship come to your mind, feel free to share.
My question is whether $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ implies that for a subsequence $X_{n_K}$ we have that $\sum \mathbb{P}(|X_{n_m} -X|<2^{-m}) < \infty$, subsequential complete convergence that is (we have here chosen $\varepsilon_m = 2^{-m}$ but any other choice would have been fine as long as $\varepsilon_m \to 0$).
My reasoning was to use the $\sup$ characterization of a.s. convergence (that is: we have a.s. convergence iff $\mathbb{P}(\sup_n |X_n -X| > 2^{-m}) \to 0$ for all m) to elect an index subsequence $(n_m)$ that satisfies $\mathbb{P}(\sup_n |X_{n_m} -X| > 2^{-m}) < 2^{-m}$, thus yielding the convergence of the above series.
Does that seem reasonable? Do you happen to know more insightful results? Thank you.
